# Syntax Explanation for SHA-1 Hash Function in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The above is a SHA1 hash function for VB.NET.

```
Function getSHA1Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
        Dim sha1Obj As New Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)
        bytesToHash = sha1Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
        Dim strResult As String = ""
        For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
            strResult += b.ToString("x2")
        Next
        Return strResult
End Function
```

Please could someone explain the code above (Visual Basic .NET), specifically the lines below -

```
bytesToHash = sha1Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
strResult += b.ToString("x2")
```

Answer (score 0):

SHA1 creates a hash (array of bytes) representing the value strToHash. The foreach is just converting this array of bytes into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a byte array containing the hash

```
bytesToHash = sha1Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)
```

Loop through each byte just created

```
For Each b As Byte In bytesToHash
```

Append to the string the hex value of each byte

```
strResult += b.ToString("x2")
```

See this for into on hex format of ToString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString